# android: grant access to write on external beside manifest

Tags: android, image, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-external-storage

I have inside the manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But when I run the app (it is supposed to create and pop up a card as an image), the image is not created.

Then I manually change the app's permissions (enabling the external storage permission: `settings->applications->Myapp->permissions`), and the app works fine.

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: inside my manifest I have:
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Comment: which version that phone has

Answer (score 0):

If your version is below android 6 (Marshmallow) you can use this code without checking for permissions:

```
final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_CODE);
```

Otherwise you need a different approach :

```
    public static boolean checkIfPermissionNeeded(Activity activity) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
   activity.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
     return true;
    }

    return false;
    }
```

In case this returns `true` you can use the code in the first block.

So :

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case REQUEST_CODE:

            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                //task may be continued
                permission = true;
            }
            else{
                //task cancelled
                permission = false;

            }
            break;

    }
}
```

And in your activity , if permission is `true` you can continue with the desired action.

Comment: So, this has to do with MM and granting permissions during the first use? Or I am wrong?

Comment: Yeah. Since in MM everytime you need a user to allow an app to use certain features a dialog will pop-up. Hence the permission could true or not; I should've been more specific.